# C++/CLI Native or Managed?

Tags: c++-cli, mixed-mode

I have a C# project and I need a C++ native code to interact with the C# code. To do so, I am using a C++/CLI class wrapper that will call a C++ class.

As far as I understand, if a C++ class has a `ref` behind it's declaration, it's going to be compiled as managed code. And if it doesn't have it, it will be compiled as native code.

Is this assumption correct or do I need to give the compiler further instructions to assure that my class will be native code?

Comment: _"if a C++ class has a ref...it's going to be compiled as managed code"_ - Not sure about that. A c++/CLI `ref class` can contain both native and CLI types.  e.g. A `ref class` that has a `void*` pointer in it.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2012/11/14/c-cli-and-mixed-mode-programming.aspx

Comment: Anyone cares to point out why the -1 votes?

Comment: Could be angry C++ coders emphasizing the "How the expletive deleted should I know? That's not a C++ question." There's no such thing as `ref` in C++.

Comment: I asked a question with the title and tag c++/cli, so it covers both languages and the ref modifier

Comment: I will read that article, thanks @Micky

Comment: Which "both languages"? CLI is not a language, C++/CLI is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I understand, if a C++ class has a ref behind it's declaration, it's going to be compiled as managed code.

Correct.  `ref class` types cannot be compiled without `/clr`.

> And if it doesn't have it, it will be compiled as native code.

Incorrect.  If `/clr` is in effect (e.g. not disabled by `#pragma unmanaged`) then the compiler is only generating MSIL (Microsoft intermediate language, the bytecode for .NET).

Comment: But I am calling c++ libraries from inside it... I assumed that if the code is bring able to interact with native libraries, it was supposed to be native... So I guess MSIL is wrapping these function calls?

Comment: _"If /clr is in effect...then the compiler is only generating MSIL"_ - do you mean **/clr:pure**? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx

Comment: Most naive operations have MSIL versions.  Not always as efficient, but still functional.

Comment: @Micky: There are two potential sources of native (non-MSIL) machine code, which cause a mixed-mode assembly to be produced: code in your project, and static libraries that get linked in.  While I understand there are a handful of cases where the compiler generates native machine code even with `/clr`, the use of `/clr:pure` is more about controlling linking than code generation.

Comment: Ben, how does the MSIL code interact with native data then?

Comment: @mFeinstein: via direct memory operations, pretty much the same as using pointers in C# with `/unsafe`